# ArrayList polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I have a homework about Hospital Management System. I am mostly done but I have an issue about polymorphism. In my project I have 6 classes and 1 test class. These 6 classes are Doctor, OutPatient, Inpatient, Patient and Person. Doctor and Patient class extend Person class, and In/Outpatient class extend Patient class. My teacher says that a Doctor now has only 1 list for Patients, in which both Inpatients and Outpatients can be added (polymorphism). This list is defined privately. So, newly added addPatient/removePatient methods will be used to add/remove patients to/from that list.

How can I do that? Whic class I have to write in/outpatient array list. Here is my code

**Doctor.java**

```
public class Doctor extends Person{

    private int staffId;
    private double salary;

    public ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

    public ArrayList<Inpatient> inpatients = new ArrayList<Inpatient>();
    public ArrayList<Outpatient> outpatients = new ArrayList<Outpatient>();
    ...
public void addPatient(Patient a) {
        JFrame j=new JFrame();

        for (int i = 0; i < patients.size(); i++) {
            if ( (patients.get(i)).getRegistrationId() == a.getRegistrationId()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j,"Patient already added before!");
                return;
            }
        }

        patients.add(a);
    }

    public void removePatient(int registrationId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < patients.size(); i++) {
            if (patients.get(i).getRegistrationId() == registrationId) {
                patients.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

**test.java**

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   ... 
 Doctor d = new Doctor(111222, "ali", 50, "m", "ankara", 6000); //staffId, name, age, sex, address, salary
 h.addDoctor(d);
 Inpatient in = new Inpatient(333444, "veli", 32, "m", "istanbul", 345.40, 410);
 d.addPatient(in); //Inpatient in is registered to Doctor d.
 Outpatient out = new Outpatient(555666, "helin", 28, "f", "izmir", 610.35);
 d.addPatient(out); //Outpatient out is registered to Doctor d.

...
```

Comment: *This list is defined privately.* -- All the lists in your example are public.

Comment: @NicholasK okey, I will fix that.

Comment: Can you reformat your question? What you need to do?

Comment: @GolovPavel I cannot understand what teacher wants? I must have only one arraylist in doctor class but where in/outpatient arraylist should be?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem? Your `addPatient()` and `removePatient()` look fine. Also, you need just one `patients` list (due to polymorphism).

Comment: *My teacher says that a Doctor now has only 1 list for Patients*: but your code has 3 separate lists. Do just what he/she said: remove the two other lists (that your code doesn't use anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that your teacher meant, that you don't need `inpatients` and `outpatients` lists at all. When you created `patients` array list, you can contain both the patients there, because they extend `Patient` class.

Answer (score 1):

so, as Pavel said, you do not need the lists for InPatients and OutPatients, just have the one for patients, and polymorphism will take care of both types. In your code you do not use he lists anyway, so just remove the declaration.

Also, a couple more remarks. When you initialise a generic, if your declaration type and the initialisation type are the same, you do not need to mention the type the second time. 
For example, here:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In this case the second mention of "String" is redundant and can be omitted.

Also, not sure where you are with your Java education but as your list grows, if will take more and more time to check whether a patient has already been added. So, using a list might not be the best idea. I would use a Map so you can look up whether a patient is already in there faster. Same goes for removing. You will also not need the loops anymore. Hope that helps!